# Creating Custom routing in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, routes

I have tried to use Alto Router library but its not working properly

I have already asked question here
[Alto Router not working for controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883436/alto-router-not-working-for-controllers)

Now i am trying to do own routing url .i can able to split url but i dont know how to make it user friendly

```
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);
print_r($uri_segments);
```

my controllers are in

> app\Controllers directory

but i want to access methods from controller like

> localhost/projectname/controllername/methodname

can any one help me how to work on this.thanks

Comment: @hassan.thanks but i am looking for simple and lightwieght framework .i dont have option to use librarys in my project since alto router had only one class so i used

Comment: you want url based router ? for example: `localhost/projectname/home/index` means access `index` method from `home` controller ? or you want user-defined router, like alto or laravel router?

Comment: dont have the option to use libraries ... what does that even mean, you are going to reinvent an entire framework?

Comment: @lagbox.its client requirement.it doesnt mean that entire framework .its just formated coding like mvc pattern.

Comment: @hassan,both options are okay for me

Comment: I see in your other question use have named controller  HomeController should on have first letter upper case  Homecontroller and also codeigniter 3 version not work with namespace.